# Proving inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}} \leq \sqrt{3 \left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In the pdf which you can download [here](https://web.williams.edu/go/math/sjmiller/public_html/161/articles/Riasat_BasicsOlympiadInequalities.pdf) I found the following inequality which I can't solve it.

> **Exercise 2.1.11** Let $a,b,c  \gt 0$. Prove that 
>   $$\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}} \leq \sqrt{3 \left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}.$$

Thanks :)

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for editing my exercises :)

Comment: maybe taking square on both side would help

Comment: below of this page is solutions and hints,please check it

Comment: @dato can you give the link. I can't find the page with the solutions and hints. Thanks

Comment: @Iuli That pdf link is no longer valid.

Comment: See also: [Proving an Olympiad type inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}}\le\sqrt{3(\frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240607)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving an Olympiad type inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}}\le\sqrt{3(\frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240607/proving-an-olympiad-type-inequality-sqrt-frac2abc-sqrt-frac2bac)

Comment: In case somebody wonders why I suggested older question as a duplicate of the recently posted one, I will add link to [related discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36791190#36791190). And I'll add link to the discussion on the meta explaining that age is not the only thing to keep in mind when choosing duplicates: [Original post marked as duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16417#16418).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using cauchy Schwarz or AM-QM we have that $$LHS \leq \sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{b+c}}$$ It suffices to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a}{b+c}\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac ab$$ By homogeneity we may suppose $a+b+c=1$.

Clearing out denominators this reduces to show $$2\sum_{cyc}a(a+b)(a+c)abc\leq \sum_{cyc}a^2c(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$ which is equivalent to $$0\leq\sum_{cyc} a^2c(a+c)(a+b)(b+c-2bc)$$ which is true by AM-GM and the fact that $a, b, c\leq 1$.

Comment: I have a question or two. 1) Why $a+b+c=1$ and 2) if we don't know that $a+b+c=1$ can we solve this inequality using another tricks? thanks :)

Comment: @luli to prove the inequality for $a$,$b$, and $c$ it suffices to prove it for $a'=\frac{a}{a+b+c}$, $b'=\frac{b}{a+b+c}$, and $c'=\frac{x}{a+b+c}$. Then $0<a',b',c'<1$ and $a'+b'+c'=1$.

Comment: The inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2a}{b+c}\leq \sum\limits_{cyc}\frac ab$ is wrong. Try $a=10$, $b=2$ and $c=1$.

Comment: This solution in incorrect...

Comment: @Iuli: Have you checked whether the claims that this answer is mistaken are true? If they are, are you going to unaccept this answer or not?

Comment: @AlexM. I do not understand your first question. Thanks!

Comment: @Iuli: This answer is mistaken, as explained by **Michael Rozenberg** above. Why don't you unaccept it?

Answer (score 1):

By C-S 
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+c}{b+c}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+c}{b+c}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3a^6c^3+3a^5b^4+6a^5c^4+a^6b^2c+2a^6c^2b+4a^5b^3c+4a^5c^3b+7a^4b^4c+$$
$$+a^5b^2c^2-11a^4b^3c^2-12a^4c^3b^2-8a^3b^3c^3)\geq0,$$
which is obviously true.

Done!

Comment: @Iuli Solution of uforoboa is total wrong. What do you think about my solution?

Comment: Your solution seems right, and the other (accepted solution as of this time) is incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Why is the last claim "obviously" true? It might be true, but why obviously? I'm staring at it and I don't see how to quickly prove it.

Comment: @Alex M Because any term with"+" $\geq$ than any term with "-" For example $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^5b^2c^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^4b^3c^2$ it's $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^4\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3b$, which is true by Rearrangement.