# Proving an Olympiad type inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}}\le\sqrt{3(\frac{a}b+\frac{b}c+\frac{c}a)}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c>0$ be real numbers. Prove that:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{a+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}}\leq\sqrt{3\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)} $$

Comment: is this from Mathlinks?

Comment: @dr.sonnhardgraubner  I don't know , I got it in a PDF document on Olympiad inequalities.

Comment: Could you give a link to that document?

Comment: @markfischler yes, here it is : http://www.aam.org.in/site/st_material/14.pdf

Comment: A page number would also be useful :)

Comment: @david its pg. no. 14 exercise 2.1.11

Comment: Thanks much! At first glance, this looks like an application of cauchy-schwarz (perhaps followed by something like AM-GM)...

Comment: This seems to be the same inequality as in this question: [Proving inequality $\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c}{a+b}} \leq \sqrt{3 \left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189140).

Comment: I found it using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B2a%7D%7Bb%2Bc%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B2b%7D%7Ba%2Bc%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B2c%7D%7Ba%2Bb%7D%7D%5Cleq%5Csqrt%7B3%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Ba%7D%5Cright)%7D%24&p=1) and only later I noticed that it is also shown among related question in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S 
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+c}{b+c}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+c}{b+c}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3a^6c^3+3a^5b^4+6a^5c^4+a^6b^2c+2a^6c^2b+4a^5b^3c+4a^5c^3b+7a^4b^4c+$$
$$+a^5b^2c^2-11a^4b^3c^2-12a^4c^3b^2-8a^3b^3c^3)\geq0,$$
which is obviously true.

Done!

Comment: oh man Michael beaten!

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Why???

Comment: For reference about "$\sum_{cyc}$": http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Cyclic_sum

Comment: How on earth is that last equality obviously true? What am I missing?

Comment: i'm also calculating the whole time to find the trick, why is that true.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen It's obvious because any term with $+$ greater or equal  to any term with $-$. For example, it's obvious that $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^5b^2c^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^4b^3c^2$.

Comment: and again why is that? We have $a,b,c > 0$, not $a,b,c > 1$.

Comment: @Andreas By AM-GM $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^5b^2c^2=a^2b^2c^2\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3=\frac{1}{3}a^2b^2c^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^3+b^3)\geq\frac{1}{3}a^2b^2c^2\sum\limits_{cyc}3\sqrt[3]{a^6b^3}=\sum\limits_{cyc}a^4b^3c^2$.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I see it now. I just wonder whether everybody here would agree to declaring this as "obvious".